# How can I make my Java web application available at the root url?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I'm using Apache Tomcat 7.

Is there a way I can deploy a web application to tomcat so that the web archive is named something like myapp.war, but have it be accessible at the root url instead of at /myapp?

I know I can name it ROOT.war but I'd prefer to keep the web archive name as it is. Is that possible? I'd also like to avoid clever tricks with symlinks if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the post http://josefbetancourt.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/tomcat7-change-root-app/